# time difference 1 second between AWS (amazaon web service) and Microsoft server

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, time, windows-server, ntp

There is a difference in 1 second between server (windows 2016 synchronized with time.windows.com) and third party web service (deployed on AWS - amazon web service).

The problem is: i send a request with a date parameter `Date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")` to TPS (third party service) and get a response with a date less than sent (difference up to 1 second). Date in request is a creation date of request  and same in response, creation date of response.

**request** :
*"timestamp":"2018-10-24T01:33:12Z"*

**response** :
*"timestamp":"2018-10-24T01:33:11.0000138Z"*

Could someone explain  the time difference ? and how to fix this issue correctly

Comment: Why is this a problem? Sometimes servers aren't exact. That's just a fact of life

Comment: it cause a problem for me , i  thought time is same for all and everywhere

Comment: Can you just subtract a second or two from the date you send? You're really not going to magically get two servers to be within a few milliseconds of each other unless you're NASA or something

Comment: Server precision apart (which is the actual issue here) : *"I thought time is same for all and everywhere"* -> This *should* be true on the earth surface, but generally this is not even true (in a physics sense), unfortunately. (e.g. : your computer system embedded in a space vessel to mars versus on the ground at Houston)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network latency, and different NTP servers between the 2 platforms could explain a 1s difference. You are likely using 2 different time references in your above setup. That alone could account for the drift.

Certainly different apps or use cases would require more or less precision. 1 to 2 seconds could be unacceptable for some setups.  In my experience 100ms sync precision/jitter can be achieved via normal NTP using the same reference clock.

See 
https://serverfault.com/questions/724409/how-accurate-can-we-get-computer-clocks-synchronized-in-a-local-network-of-any-n for a good discussion on issues impacting NTP time sync precision.

See also https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/ on how AWS manages their reference NTP clocks.

For an overview of NTP Network Time Protocol see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Comment: the date in response is set  by third party , i can't do anything with timestamp in response

Comment: I would ask to know their NTP setup if possible, and use the same clock that they use.

Comment: A 1 second difference, particularly backwards, is clearly wrong and means that *somebody* has a clock that is, in fact, wrong. The simple question is "who?"  NTP can do a much better job than this, even several strata deep, and to accept such a skew as attributable to different sources is unreasonable.  Windows has historically been very sloppy with time sync, keeping clocks within a few seconds, maybe.  Server 2016 is better, though I am unsure now much better it is by default. Possibly useful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/accurate-time

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other interesting answer :

If you want to get an ordering of responses and request, then you should use a timestamp produced by the same machine (the sender of the request), not trust and compare timestamps produced by different machines.

Only there you can guarantee a sequential logical ordering of timestamps  consistent with the order of requests / response.

Also, don't forget that the timestamps written in headers are basically data that could be forged, if it's coming for a third-party source.

Comment: when third party service receive my request , timestamp from request is compared with third parties server time

Comment: You mean : *third-party server* compares request timestamp with third parties server time ? Then maybe you should  have some synchronization in place to use a common time server. But there is an inherent latency in using internet, so you won't be able to avoid difference of time. You could avoid the incorrect ordering of time, by first requesting a timestamp from the time server, then using this timestamp as value in your request. But it is quite involved for low benefit. Why is sthis an issue actually ?